# How to Consume IIS hosted HTML file on a remote android device

Tags: android, html, iis, cordova-2.0.0

My HTML5 file is Hosted in `IIS`. My hosted file name is authSample.HTML.
On desktop browser (Like chrome, firefox, IE), I am able to run my hosted HTML file using below URL.

```
 http://localhost/authSample.HTML      // localhost is my ipaddress
```

But I need to run my file on Android OS using certain OS specific functionality like GeoLocation etc. So I need to make use of Phonegap(Cordova).

Is there any way that I can Host Cordova Android HTML files on IIS and try to open the files on Android Phone Browser?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
super.loadUrl("http://localhost/authSample.HTML") // localhost is my ipaddress
```

with an actual IP address. That's the obvious thing to try.